# I have an MZ4 thermistor, I can't find info about the value of capacitance

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, capacitance, thermistor, diy

I have bought a self assembly kit for power source ([based on the LM317](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001308880138.html)). The provided small thermistors are tagged as [MZ4](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32724931606.html). I did my research but couldn't find the datasheet. The PCB is showing them to solder in place of 0.1uF capacitors.

How does a thermistor become a capacitor?

In future encounters of thermistors how do I know their capacitance? (I have no measurement gear besides a multimeter.)

Comment: Why do you think they are thermistors (other than the part number?) Can you measure the resistance (1K roughly)? If so, perhaps it is an error in the kitting. If not, then it's possible they are capacitors with a similar part number to thermistors (part numbers are not guaranteed unique).

Comment: I find it unlikely that a power supply would need thermistors / PTCs. Are you sure that they are thermistors? With your multimeter on ohms range, measure the resistance of the components marked MZ4. If these are capacitors you would measure a very high resistance. If they show a lower resistance then don't use them but get proper 0.1 uF capacitors and use those.

Comment: @Ulsa:  Please post a photo of the parts you have as well as the schematic diagram of the circuit.

Comment: the resistance is around 200-300k. So how high is "high resistance" in @Bimpelrekkie 's comment.

Comment: Also @JRE the photo of the board could be found on the link. As well as the picture of the parts

Comment: @SpehroPefhany These were the parts left out of the kit, besides the original link also has them on the place they are on. Besides that I found that ptc thermistors could be used as inrush current limiters on followink [link](https://www.ametherm.com/blog/inrush-current/capacitor-inrush-current) and [link2](https://product.tdk.com/en/techlibrary/applicationnote/howto_ptc-limiter.html)

Still that doesnt explain why PCB marks them as 0.1uF

Comment: *Besides that I found that ptc thermistors could be used as inrush current limiters* Yes PTCs can be used as current limiters but that will be PTCs with a very **low** resistance (a few ohms) and not 200 - 300 k ohm. The MZ4 is supposed to be 1000 ohms (at 120C) so your measured value **makes no sense**. Are you sure you're not measuring the resistance between your fingers? Are you not touching **ANY** electrical wire while testing? I really advise you to discard these vague components, if you aren't 100% sure what they are I'd just use proper components.

Comment: There are 0.1 uF capacitors that look almost identical to those thermistors. But they will read MUCH higher than 300K resistance ... unless you are holding the leads to the probes with your fingers.

Comment: @Ulsa:  I asked for photos of **your** parts because the photos on the Aliexpress page are too fuzzy to read the printing on the parts.  Even if it could be read, that still wouldn't tell you if the wrong parts were packed in your kit.  Post photos of **your** parts.

Comment: If they were left out of the kit, how did you come about having them?

Comment: The kit uses 2 (pairs) of thermistor, I only had one in my hand